# Using multiple webpack methods on laravel elixir

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir, enoent

I'm using Laravel 5.3 and Elixir:

```
"laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
"laravel-elixir-rollup-official": "^1.0.5",
"laravel-elixir-vue": "^0.1.4",
"laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
```

I'm using multiple `wepback` methods in my `gulpfile.js` file, as you can see here:

```
elixir(mix => {
    mix
        .copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/build/fonts')
        .sass('client.scss', 'public/css/client.css')
        .sass('panel.scss', 'public/css/panel.css')
        // .webpack('app.js')
        .webpack('panel.js')
        .version(['css/client.css', 'css/panel.css', 'js/app.js', 'js/panel.js']);
});
```

I've noticed that (sometimes) when I use multiple webpack methods, and run `gulp watch`, I get this error:

```
stream.js:74
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
  ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '...\build\js\app-6ced943929.js'
at Error (native)
```

Is it wrong to use multiple times with the method `webpack`? Is there an alternative way to separate 2 different js files?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure regarding this particular case, but you can just invoke a new stream for this and you should be able to avoid the issue:

```
mix.webpack('app.js');

mix.webpack('panel.js');
```

Of course your `.version()` would then need to be added to each stream separately so there is the introduction of a bit of code redundancy.